# How to get array elements based on conditions using javascript array reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So I have an array

```
const records = [
{
    value: 24,
    gender: "BOYS"
},
{
    value: 42,
    gender: "BOYS"
},
{
    value: 85,
    gender: "GIRLS"
},
{
    value: 12,
    gender: "GIRLS"
},
{
    value: 10,
    gender: "BOYS"
}
```

]

And I want to get only "Boys" objects within an array using js reduce() rather than filter().
Please help.

Comment: What is the reason for using `reduce` over `filter`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried anything? If you can show your trials, we may help you to fix it.

Comment: I suggest that you use neither `.filter` nor `.reduce`, but `.flatMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уou can use any option you want

```js
const records = [{value: 24,gender: "BOYS"},{value: 42,gender: "BOYS"},{value: 85,gender: "GIRLS"},{value: 12,gender: "GIRLS"},{value: 10,gender: "BOYS"}]

const withReduce = records.reduce((acc, item) => item.gender === "BOYS" ? [...acc, item] : acc, []);
const withFlatMap = records.flatMap(item => item.gender === "BOYS" ? item : []);
const withFilter = records.filter(({ gender }) => gender === "BOYS");

console.log(withReduce);
console.log(withFlatMap);
console.log(withFilter);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: @shohan You can upvote or mark as accepted any answer that helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
const records = [
{
    value: 24,
    gender: "BOYS"
},
{
    value: 42,
    gender: "BOYS"
},
{
    value: 85,
    gender: "GIRLS"
},
{
    value: 12,
    gender: "GIRLS"
},
{
    value: 10,
    gender: "BOYS"
}

]

let boys = records.reduce((t,o)=>{
  if(o.gender === "BOYS") t.push(o)
  return t
},[])
console.log(boys)
```